# Infinity norm of the inverse of a matrix with integer coefficients

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $k$-dimensional non singualar matrix with integer coefficients. Is it true that $\|A^{-1}\|_\infty \leq 1$? How can I show that? Could you give me a counterexample?It is clear that $\|A^{-1}\|_{\infty}=\frac{1}{\min\{\|Ax\|_{\infty}:\|x\|_{\infty}=1\}}$. My idea is to show that the minimum is obtained on an integer point so the denominator is bigger than $1$. Is mi idea right?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

It is not true.

Note that inf-norm on matrices is the max absolute sum of per row.

Thus

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\-2 & 1\end{bmatrix}, A^{-1}=-\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\2 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

is a counter example.

Answer (score 3):

I presume that by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ for matrices you mean the matrix norm induced by the $\|\cdot \|_\infty$ norm on vectors.  Then you are right that
$$ \|A^{-1}\|_\infty = \frac{1}{\min \{ \|Ax\|_\infty \; : \; \|x\|_\infty = 1\}}$$
But there is no reason to think that the minimum is obtained for an integer point, and
it is not true that $\|A^{-1}\|_\infty \le 1$.  For example, consider
$$ A = \pmatrix{3 & -4\cr 2 & -3\cr}$$
which has $A^{-1} = A$.